# Visual Studio Reports - Static table at end of report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to place a static table with static data at the end of a generated report but when i do it repeats the table rather than show it once.

How do i create a static table with some definitions at the end of a report. Idea being that tab 2 of an excel will be a list of contract definitions that never change.

Comment: I'm guessing you have the static part within the main tablix. Can you add a separate table below the main tablix?

Comment: It still seems to repeat. I may have found a workarounds but its not ideal. I put several textboxes in and make them look like a table. Then put a pagebreak after the existing tablix that spreads across several pages dynamically. Formatting doesn't look great on the group of textboxes but its acceptable for a few rows.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post an image of the report design. It's difficult to understand exactly what you are doing without seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the page break option on your final static table to "Start"

If that doesn't work:

Add a separate rectangle at the bottom (after all your tables).  Set the page break on the rectangle properties to "Start".  Add your static table inside the rectangle. (Cut table and paste while rectangle is selected to make sure it's in there).

This is assuming that it's not something data related in your "static" table that it causing it to repeat.